# Enviando html personalizado con django

Tags: django, django-forms, django-admin

ok yo envio correo y todo ya con un template, pero necesito mostrar los datos que ya estan registrados del usuario en dicho template y no lo esta haciendo, solo muestra las etiquetas del html, ayuda por favor.
Yo sé, que las {{}}, incluyen los datos del user en la etiqueta, pero no las muestra a la hora de renderizar el template en el correo, no salen, solo muestra los ecabezados de la tabla del html.

```
views.py
def solit(request):
"""Gestion de solicitudes"""
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = SolitForm(request.POST, instance=request.user)
        if form.is_valid():
           form.save()
           subject = 'Welcome {}'.format(request.user)
           args = {'user': request.user}
           from_email = 'jadamson@mail.com'
           html_content = render_to_string('timeup/send_mail.html', 
   {'form':form})
           text_content = strip_tags(html_content)
           msg = EmailMultiAlternatives(subject, text_content, from_email, 
   ['jadamson@mail.com'])
           msg.attach_alternative(html_content, 'timeup/send_mail.html')
           msg.send()
        return redirect('index')
    else:
       form = SolitForm(instance=request.user)
       args = {'form':form}`introducir el código aquí`
   return render(request, 'timeup/solicitudes.html', args)


name.html
{% block content %}
<table class="table">
    <thead class="thead-dark">
      <tr>
        <th scope="col">#</th>
        <th scope="col">No. Empleado</th>
        <th scope="col">Nombre</th>
        <th scope="col">Apellido</th>
        <th scope="col">Inicio de Labores</th>
        <th scope="col">Area</th>
        <th scope="col">Dias Disponibles</th>
        <th scope="col">Horas Disponibles</th>
        <th scope="col">Inicio de Vacaciones</th>
        <th scope="col">Fin de Vacaciones</th>
        <th scope="col">Ultimas Vacaciones</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <th scope="row">{{ user.consecutivo }}</th>
        <td>{{ user.numero_empleado }}</td>
        <td>{{ user.nombre }}</td>
        <td>{{ user.apellido }}</td>
        <td>{{ user.F_init }}</td>
        <td>{{ user.area }}</td>
        <td>{{ user.D_pendientes }}</td>
        <td>{{ user.H_pendientes }}</td>
        <td>{{ user.Init_vac }}</td>
        <td>{{ user.Fin_vac }}</td>
        <td>{{ user.ul_vac_tomadas }}</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
  <table class="table">
    <thead class="thead-light">
      <tr>
  </table>
  {% endblock %}
```

Comment: "name.html" es lo que deseas enviar por email ? si es asi fijate que dentro de context en "render_to_string" estas mandando "form" no "user" como deseas acceder en el template

Comment: @DiegoAvila si error de redaccion en cuanto al archivo send_mail.html, no entiendo Ya le puse: html_content = render_to_string('timeup/send_mail.html', {'user':UserProfile}) donde "UserProfile": es mi modelo personalizado. Disculpa, es que no entiendo muy bien eso del contexto.

Comment: te sugiero revisar esto: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2810245/5215609 y tambien: https://anymail.readthedocs.io/en/stable/tips/django_templates/#using-django-templates-for-email

Answer (score 0):

En tu código renderizas `send_mail.html` pero no `name.html` que es la plantilla que has adjuntado.
Igualmente, no estás pasando la variable `user` a la plantilla, estás pasando `form`, por lo que `user` no existe en plantilla.

Comment: si error de redaccion en cuanto al archivo send_mail.html, no entiendo Ya le puse: html_content = render_to_string('timeup/send_mail.html', {'user':UserProfile}) donde "UserProfile": es mi modelo personalizado. Disculpa, es que no entiendo muy bien eso del contexto.

Comment: El contexto en definitiva es insertarle variables a la plantilla para poder usarla en ésta. El nombre que le pongas como clave en el diccionario ('contexto' en tu caso) es como debes de invocar a la variable desde la plantilla.

Answer (score 0):

trata cargando la plantilla con loader y cambia la forma en la que adjuntas el html_content

```
 from django.template import loader
 html_content = loader.render_to_string('timeup/send_mail.html', {'user':UserProfile})
 msg.attach_alternative(html_content, "text/html")
```